# Able to receive a wifi packet through a Zigbee chip

Tags: wifi, wireless, zigbee

I have a wireless sensor network deployed in a building. Each node is in a separate room. All the sensory data goes to a datastore.

The user once he/she gets to a room should be able to get the sensory data on his phone from the datastore, provided that we know in which room he/she is. GPS does not give high accurary neither infering it from the wifi signal strength. We thought of having the phone send a dummy frame through wifi that can be intercepted by the sensor node and then based on the node who gets it, or gets it first (in case many nodes intercept that frame) should give an indication to the system of what room the user is in

Wifi and Zigbee both communicate on 2.4Ghz. Is there a way I can intercept all the RF signals from the Zigbee node and entrepret the frame even if it is not a a Zigbee frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible, they use different signaling methods.